# Use variable in update execSQL statement in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I want to update the sqlite database table with a function as follows

`execSQL` works when I use 1 directly but not work when I use the variable dep

```
public void update(long id,int dep) {
    Log.i("ee","havu entered in update");

    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE deci set dp = dep WHERE _id = 1");
    //db.execSQL("UPDATE deci set dp = 1 WHERE _id = 1");
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    db.close();
    /*ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(dp, dep);
    int i = db.update(deci, contentValues );*/
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variables like this:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE deci set dp = " + dep + " WHERE _id = " + id );
```

In your code I see commented statements that use `ContentValues` 
which is always a better and safer way:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("dp", dep); 
db.update(deci , cv, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
```